# Trouble adding Brother printer to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, printing, brother

I have Ubuntu 21.10 installed and can't get my Brother MFC-7860DW recognized/connected to print over my network. I've downloaded and installed the drivers from the Brother website using the terminal, but I was unable to print a test page.

In the Printer Properties I'm getting the following message:

```
Processing - Unable to locate printer "printer_IP_address"
```

I'm pretty sure I have the printer URI address set up correctly (it's just the "printer IP address", right? I put `ipp://_printer_IP_address/ipp/print` (this didn't work either)).

The `ping` command in the terminal gives me the following results: `ping: printer_IP_address: Name or service not known`

How do I fix this and get the printer to work over the network?

Comment: Drivers shouldn't be needed in current releases.

Comment: If you cannot ping the IP address, then it is a networking issue.  Using the printer's menu button (or settings button) look at your network settings.  If it is connected via WiFi, make sure the WLAN settings show a connection to the network.  You may need to go through your printer's network setup function.

Comment: Did you try adding the printer using CUPS?  http://localhost:631/

Comment: Are you in a position to connect it (temporarily) via usb cable? That would at least allow you to confirm the printer & drivers are all working. For my brother printer, I got the IP address from the printer’s lcd: on the printer itself, press ‘menu’ then choose ‘network’ then ‘TCP address’ and it shows you directly on the printer’s LCD display. Hope that helps.